# Unable to execute UHD sample c++ code

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I'm trying to execute **UHD C++ sample code** given [here](https://kb.ettus.com/Getting_Started_with_UHD_and_C%2B%2B),

```
#include <uhd/utils/thread_priority.hpp>
#include <uhd/utils/safe_main.hpp>
#include <uhd/usrp/multi_usrp.hpp>
#include <uhd/exception.hpp>
#include <uhd/types/tune_request.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int UHD_SAFE_MAIN(int argc, char *argv[]) {
uhd::set_thread_priority_safe();

std::string device_args("addr=192.168.10.2");
std::string subdev("A:0");
std::string ant("TX/RX");
std::string ref("internal");

double rate(1e6);
double freq(915e6);
double gain(10);
double bw(1e6);

//create a usrp device
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << boost::format("Creating the usrp device with: %s...") % device_args << std::endl;
uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);

// Lock mboard clocks
std::cout << boost::format("Lock mboard clocks: %f") % ref << std::endl;
usrp->set_clock_source(ref);

//always select the subdevice first, the channel mapping affects the other settings
std::cout << boost::format("subdev set to: %f") % subdev << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_subdev_spec(subdev);
std::cout << boost::format("Using Device: %s") % usrp->get_pp_string() << std::endl;

//set the sample rate
if (rate <= 0.0) {
    std::cerr << "Please specify a valid sample rate" << std::endl;
    return ~0;
}

// set sample rate
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Rate: %f Msps...") % (rate / 1e6) << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_rate(rate);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Rate: %f Msps...") % (usrp->get_rx_rate() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set freq
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Freq: %f MHz...") % (freq / 1e6) << std::endl;
uhd::tune_request_t tune_request(freq);
usrp->set_rx_freq(tune_request);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Freq: %f MHz...") % (usrp->get_rx_freq() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the rf gain
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Gain: %f dB...") % gain << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_gain(gain);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Gain: %f dB...") % usrp->get_rx_gain() << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the IF filter bandwidth
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Bandwidth: %f MHz...") % (bw / 1e6) << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_bandwidth(bw);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Bandwidth: %f MHz...") % (usrp->get_rx_bandwidth() / 1e6) << std::endl << std::endl;

// set the antenna
std::cout << boost::format("Setting RX Antenna: %s") % ant << std::endl;
usrp->set_rx_antenna(ant);
std::cout << boost::format("Actual RX Antenna: %s") % usrp->get_rx_antenna() << std::endl << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

I can successfully build<kbd>F6</kbd> the project under `Debug`mode,

[image]

Now if I try to execute<kbd>F5</kbd> the project under `Debug` mode, it throws this warning & pauses execution.

[image]

& then I tried to locate where it fails, using break points & found that during the creation of `usrp object`

```
 uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::sptr usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(device_args);
```

It would be great if someone points me towards the right direction & why it's failing at this point?

**Edit 1:** Hitting **Break** takes to `free.c` (Acc. to IInspectable suggestion)

[image]

Comment: The access violation dialog already tells you, where it's failing. You simply need to click the *Break* button and it'll take you right to the place where things go downhill.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks! yes I tried that it takes to free.c file which is not part of the main project & it says (unknown scope).

Comment: That location certainly comes with a call stack. That is invaluably helpful in diagnosing the root cause.